# Set of points of solid triangle in plane

Tags: geometry, triangles, plane-geometry

Consider a triangle in the plane with vertices $a,b,c$ (viewed as vectors). I'm struggling to understand why the region of the solid triangle is given by
$\{t_1a+t_2b+t_3c:t_i\in [0,1], \Sigma_{i=1}^{3}t_i=1\}$. The inside looks like a dot product of sorts, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Firstly, the $t_i$'s are scalars and $\mathbf{a,b,c}$ are vectors so it is not a dot product in the manner you might be thinking. Secondly, start with two vectors $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$, then consider the linear combinations of the form $s\mathbf{a}+(1-s)\mathbf{b}$, where $s \in [0,1]$. Ask yourself, what does this represent geometrically? Hint: with $s=0$ we get $\mathbf{b}$ and with $s=1$ we get $\mathbf{a}$.

Comment: That represents the line segment from b to a, yes. But how does that generalise?

Comment: @user170231 That was useful in that it redirected me to the wiki page for convex combinations, which my question is ultimately a special case of. I now understand it having worked it out using this geometrical argument: every point in or on a triangle can be reached by first moving along one edge to a point, and then along the line segment from that point to a second side where this line segment is parallel to the third side. A bit of renaming of scalar factors completes the proof. Thanks